# por qué bulkCopy inserta solo 5848 registros

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net

Tengo un fileupload para importar una base en Excel a la base de datos de SQL server 2012, el código funciona al parecer, cuando cargo el archivo y presiono el botón, carga exactamente 5848 registros y en la base de Excel existen 9999 registros.

Entonces lo que me entra en curiosidad es que hay otro boton con el mismo código, una que otra modificación pero lo que cambia en si es la tabla de destino y el excel tiene diferentes columnas, este segundo boton y excel cargan 9999 registros sin problema.

Para aclarar la pregunta, por qué este bulkcopy inserta solamente 5848 registros, y el otro si inserta 9999 registros, realmente necesito que inserte incluso 99.000 registros de ser el caso aunque supongo sería una carga para el servidor bastante alta.

parte del código:

```
string path = string.Concat(Server.MapPath("~/temp/"), fileUpLoadNN.FileName);
                        fileUpLoadNN.SaveAs(path);

                        string excelConnectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=Excel 8.0", path);

                        using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString))
                        {
                            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand
                                    ("Select * FROM [" + SheetName + "$]", connection);

                            connection.Open();

                            using (DbDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
                            {

                                string sqlConnectionString = @"Data Source=DELL-SQL;Initial Catalog=DATABASE; User ID=*******;Password=******;";

                                using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(sqlConnectionString))
                                {
                                    bulkCopy.BatchSize = 5000;
                                    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "BASE_PRESUPUESTO_NN";
                                    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dr);
                                    bulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 0;

                                }
                            }

                        }
```

Comment: @Alonso Fallas Gracias compa por su tiempo, agregué tal cual la línea que me dijiste, probé entre `HDR=YES y HDR=NO`, y me provoca un error: "El formato de la cadena de inicialización no se ajusta a la especificación que comienza en el índice 175." ya estoy buscando que significa eso.

Comment: Lo más importante es utilizar IMEX=1, lo agregaste? Intentalo sin agregar lo del HDR.

Comment: Si compa lo agregué y cambie a 0, también quité el HDR y da como error: `No se pudo encontrar el archivo ISAM instalable.`

Comment: Yo tenía un problema parecido al tuyo,
Cuando ejecutaba mi aplicación desde Visual Studio todo funcionaba sin problemas, pero cuando publicaba en IIS no me dejaba cargar todos los registros de los archivos de Excel, solo me cargaba cierta cantidad, por ejemplo un 20% del total de registros y lo resolví agregando "HDR=Yes, IMEX=1" a la conexión. Gracias a las personas que comentaron esta publicación, fue de gran ayuda. Gracias por compartir sus conocimientos :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pueda ser que tu problema sea debido a que un Excel contenga datos mixtos en las celdas y el otro no, y por ende el proceso se caiga haciendo que solo se inserten esa cantidad de registros. Intenta agregando `IMEX = 1` en el **connectionString**, de ésta forma:

```
string excelConnectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=Excel 8.0; HDR=No, IMEX=1", path);
```

Lo anterior es una forma más segura de obtener los datos mezclados en celdas de Excel. Además, ten en cuenta que si tu Excel tiene las primeras filas encabezados de los valores es necesario agregar `HDR=YES` al **connectionString** para que el proceso salte ésa primer columna de encabezados y nos los procese, en cuyo caso la puedes dejar como `HDR=No`